# How to compare user inputs with integers in array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of 50 integers and I need to allow a user to input any value and compare it to the 50 integers. If it's greater than any of the values I need to find out how many.

Any ideas on how I could go about this? Feels like I've been stumped for days.

EDIT: 
I assume I shall have to use a counter of some sort.

Comment: You can [edit] your post. Paste in some code you have written so far and format it by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Then include some sample input and output. Make sure you tell us what you _want_ to be output as well as what you are currently getting.

Comment: Use a for loop, create a new array with values less than input, get the length of the new array

Answer (score 1):

With the following `list` and search query:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_num = 3
```

Loop through the `list`, do your comparison, then add to a counter when needed:

```
counter = 0
for number in l:
    if my_num > number:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Alternatively, you can send a generator to `sum()` to do this concisely:

```
print(sum(1 for num in l if my_num > num))
```